# What tense should I be using here?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

> In the past, you **ought to** spend an excessive amount of time on coordinating, communicating and keeping track with the suppliers. 
>   At the same time, you **are concerned** with product warehousing, sorting, and packaging. 
>   Before your clients **could** receive the products, you **have already spent** an immense amount of money on your suppliers. Now, Kinghome has a solution for you.

Comment: In the past, you **ought to have spent**. But I don't think that's what you mean to say.  You mean **were required to spend** or **had to spend**.

Answer (score 1):

> In the past, you **ought to** spend an excessive amount of time on coordinating, communicating and keeping track with the suppliers.

"Ought" has the wrong connotation here, as though it were an external requirement imposed by someone else. "Have" is better, since it implies it's inherent to the situation. Here, the simple past is sufficient, referencing any or all of the past without any other times relevant, so it would be "you had to".

> At the same time, you **are concerned** with product warehousing, sorting, and packaging.

Present perfect is probably better for optimistic marketing: it was true up to this moment, but isn't necessarily so any longer. So "have been concerned". (If you want to be more honest, you can leave this the way it is, since the Kinghome solution is highly unlikely to *completely* remove all logistical concerns.)

> Before your clients **could** receive the products, […]

Simple present is better, since you're talking about something that is true without reference to time at all. That is, it was true in the past and will continue to be so indefinitely: there exists something that has to happen before clients receive products. (This is somewhat of a meta-reference, since there are nested tenses and thus multiple levels of time specificity; the outer one positions the inner one, which we'll get to in a bit.) So this becomes "can", although "the products" should probably become "your products" just to make it a bit more relevant.

> […] you **have already spent** an immense amount of money on your suppliers. Now, Kinghome has a solution for you.

This is fine as is, correctly using present perfect to imply something done in the past that affects the present. That is, for every occasion (simple present) on which a client receives a product, "you *have already spent*" this money (present perfect).